# A vector function with polynomial entries

Tags: matrices, polynomials, vectors

Consider a vector function $V_{n\times 1}(m)$, where $m\in \mathbb{N}$, has the property that:

$V_{n\times 1}(1)=\left[ \begin{matrix}
   1  \\
   0  \\
   \vdots   \\
   0  \\
\end{matrix} \right]$

$V_{n\times 1}(2)=\left[ \begin{matrix}
   0  \\
   1  \\
   0   \\
   \vdots  \\
\end{matrix} \right]$

and so on.

could you design polynomials for enteries in terms of $m, n$ that leads to above vector function.

It's very nice of you to help me.

Comment: What have you worked out so far?

Comment: I found something for the case which all entries are one except the $m$th entry is zero. However, this is not the case to be here.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInterpolatingPolynomial.html

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following polynomials :$$ p_1(m)= \widehat{(m-1)}(m-2)\ldots(m-n)$$
$$ p_2(m)=(m-1)\widehat{(m-2)}\ldots(m-n)$$ $$\vdots $$
$$ p_n(m)= (m-1)(m-2)\ldots\widehat{(m-n)}$$ 
where the hat signifies omission of the factor. Your vector now looks like: $V_{n \times 1}(m)=[p_1(m)/p_1(1),p_2(m)/p_2(2),\ldots,p_i(m)/p_i(i),\ldots,p_n(m)/p_n(n)]^T$.

Comment: Thank you, but in your answer $V_{n\times 1}(1)=[0,1,1,1,]$ which is not what was requested.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. If I replace $m=1$ I get $p_1(1)=(1-2)(1-3)\ldots$ which is non zero, on the other hand we have $p_2(1)=(1-1)(1-3)\ldots=0$, and likewise for $p_i(1)=0$ for $i>1$. So $V(1)=[1,0,0,0,0,\ldots]$. I edited my post I forgot the argument $(n)$ of the vector